# handling file backup/archive on success and retry on failure

Tags: spring-integration

i have setup a simple file integration the reads a files from a directory and transfer via sftp  to a  remote system. it is working fine, however i need to handle archiving after successful transfer and retry until *n if unsuccessful transfer. any advise how this can be done using spring-integration components?

```
    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="sftp.host"/>
        <property name="port" value="22"/>
        <property name="user" value="user1"/>
        <property name="password" value="pass1"/>
    </bean>

    <file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="fileInputChannel" 
         directory="C:/FileServer" 
         prevent-duplicates="true" 
         filename-pattern="*.pdf">
     <integration:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter> 

       <sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    channel="fileInputChannel"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-directory=".">
    <sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.renameTo('C:/succeeded/' + payload.name)"/>
            <property name="successChannel" ref="afterSuccessDeleteChannel"/>
            <property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload.renameTo('C:/failed/' + payload.name)"/>
            <property name="failureChannel" ref="afterFailRenameChannel" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
            <property name="retryTemplate" ref="retryTemplate"/>
        </bean>
    </sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [retry-and-more sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more). It shows how to use a retry advice and how to take different actions based on success/failure.

For both you would declare the retry advice after the expression evaluating advice so the expression evaluating advice is invoked when retries are exhausted.

Comment: i didn't get the last statement? 'for both you would declare retry advise after expression evaluating advise...'

Comment: I mean you want the retry advice "within" the scope of the expression evaluating advice (retry advice declared second in the advice chain) so the retries execute and when the retries are exhausted (or succeed) the success/failure advice can do his thing.

Comment: That worked! didn't realize I can use 2 advice in the chain. On expression evaluating advise 'onSuccessExpression' works fine renaming a file, but on onFailureExpression which also renames a file fails.  Both using 'payload.renameTo()'.

Comment: When you say "failed" do you mean the rename failed, or the rename was not executed? We have a [test case that exercises this scenario (retry exhaustion with an outer expression evaluating advice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/handler/advice/AdvisedMessageHandlerTests.java#L665). Can you edit your question to show your current configuration?

Comment: The rename failed, where I expect it to be written in the failed dir specified.  One thing that I noticed though is the source file is not deleted in this case whereas on success it gets deleted.

Comment: What is your retry template configuration? I just pasted your config into the sample (using a default retry template) and everything worked as I expected... https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/ff9346c774f474f4586733a80b67b054cd144c28 I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging (like I did in the sample).

Comment: That's strange, i thought something was wrong with my config. I even use the default retry template with the same result. I will have to turn debug to find out.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I ran the sample just to test and got the same error. 16:39:10.071 ERROR [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] Renaming of C:\FileServer\Ekling.txt after failed transfer, result:false

Comment: Stupid question - does `C:/failed/` exist? Exactly what error are you getting? I have to run, so it might be tomorrow before I can answer further.

Comment: Yes, C:/failed/ exists. I run almost the same code you tested from the samples with the 'renameTo' for success and failure changes you showed, and have turn on debug. After dropping a .txt file got this 16:50:37.224 ERROR [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] Renaming of C:\FileServer\citrix1.txt after failed transfer, result:false

Comment: run a test on a linux box and all worked fine. Looks like a bug in the File.renameTo() in a windows environment. Thanks for your help.